# ImportXML function in Google Sheets - count unique results for applied filters

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Image showing intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggAPh.png)

I need a formula to count the unique "Insider Name"s from website OpenInsider, when filtered on a particular:

- time range e.g. 6 months
- ticker e.g. LABP, APEN, SPG are 3 examples
- transaction filing type e.g. purchases

Looking at #insiders purchasing in the last 6 months for these 3 examples should yield result 3, 1, and 0 respectively.

I then also wish to sum the value of said purchases in a separate column.

Imagine in my spreadsheet column A lists the tickers, column B should be # insider purchases and column C should be value of insider purchases in that period.

Here's what I'm trying, if this helps anyone as a starting point:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("http://openinsider.com/screener?s="& A2 &"&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=180&fdr=&td=180&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=2&nfl=0&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1", "//td[6]"),2,1)
```

Comment: what is in your A2?

Comment: Ticker e.g. LABP

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the desired output? Your formula seems to work already...I assume you know how to use `SUM` so I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @iansedano - added. I get #N/A could not fetch URL for the #insiders and not sure how to do the sum of the amounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use IMPORTHTML

Its easier IMO.

Start off by simply getting the full table of a certain ticker.

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://openinsider.com/screener?s="& A3 &"&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=180&fdr=&td=180&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=2&nfl=0&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1", "table", 12)
```

This is telling Sheets to get the 12th table from that URL.

Make sure that there is enough space around it to expand and you should see something like:

[image]

What you can do then is wrap this in an INDEX function as you have done, except now you can reference the table its coming from so its much easier to pick the appropriate INDEX numbers.

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://openinsider.com/screener?s="& A2 &"&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=180&fdr=&td=180&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=2&nfl=0&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1", "table", 12),2,6)
```

This is telling Sheets to get the value in the 2nd row and 6th column in the table.

[image]

Or the 12th column for instance

[image]

This last screenshot is the "Value field". The "6m" field you mention is blank for the tickers you have listed.

#### Conditionals

If you want to fetch the data only if the Trade Type is "P-Purchase", you can do something like this:

```
=IF(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://openinsider.com/screener?s="& A2 &"&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=180&fdr=&td=180&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=2&nfl=0&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1", "table", 12),2,7) = "P - Purchase", INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://openinsider.com/screener?s="& A2 &"&o=&pl=&ph=&ll=&lh=&fd=180&fdr=&td=180&tdr=&fdlyl=&fdlyh=&daysago=&xp=1&xs=1&vl=&vh=&ocl=&och=&sic1=-1&sicl=100&sich=9999&grp=2&nfl=0&nfh=&nil=&nih=&nol=&noh=&v2l=&v2h=&oc2l=&oc2h=&sortcol=0&cnt=100&page=1", "table", 12),2,6), "Not Purchase")
```

The IF function takes 3 arguments.
1. A conditional, in this case, if the value in row 2 column 7 is "P - Purchase"
2. Value if True - The Index function again but with the value you want.
3. Value if False - I've put in "Not Purchase" but you can replace this with `0` if you want.

#### Important Note!

*If **any** of the ticker URLs lead to a page with even a slight difference in format or structure then this will likely not work. For example, if one of the tickers had less columns, then your index numbers will not correspond to what you want!*

#### Reference

- [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am however getting message "Error Loading data..." when trying both of these (with and without index).I am leaving plenty of space around the cells

Comment: It worked for me...maybe something to do with your connection?

Comment: How can I troubleshoot that? My internet is up and running

Comment: Just tried in a new, blank google sheet and it says could not fetch URL. I have checked and it is written exactly as per the hyperlink when on the relevant page

Comment: I just tried it in a new blank sheet too and it still works for me, don't know how to troubleshoot it if I can't reproduce it (literally copied from my answer and pasted in) (just in case, i'm on chrome, though I don't see why that might cause an issue)

Comment: Funnily enough it has just started working without me having changed anything. Thanks! However it is pulling in the totals for both purchases and sales, when I only want purchases. For example on ABT it returns 10 and the total of all those sales. Is there any way this could be limited to show only where column 'Trade Type' begins with P?

Comment: Counting / summing based on a particular transaction type was part of the initial question. However happy to create a new question if preferred? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Maybe you are right, its borderline, give me a bit and I'll update my answer

Comment: Hm now it's gone back to fetch URL errors on all these links. Seems very temperamental. I'm sure this will work once / if it successfully calls the URLs